# Guarantees about partial model when check-sat returns unknown

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers

I have a question about partial models from z3.
I have looked online for information about them, but sadly I have not found much, other than that they can sometimes be retrieved when a verification fails.

In case `(check-sat)` returns `unknown`, what are the guarantees about the partial model (if any can be retrieved)? Is it guaranteed to always be sound?

I'm interested specifically in the case of quantifier-related incompleteness, though I doubt that makes a difference.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are — as far as I know — no official guarantees, I expect that the (unsatisfying) answer is: the partial model heavily depends on the concrete problem and the "means" (preprocessor steps, heuristics, solvers, tactics, random seeds, timeouts, ...) Z3 applied to tackle the problem.

I therefore expect that only somebody who essentially knows the whole code base *and* your concrete problem(s) could give you a satisfying answer ... if at all.